# Вводное слово "следовательно" может быть союзом для однородных членов?

Tags: вводные-слова, союзы

Из справочника по пунктуации на сайте Грамота.ру:

*Я – русский человек, **следовательно** имею право это сказать.* С. Надсон, Дневники.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_675

**Это правильно**, запятая после *следовательно* **не ставится?**

**Примеры, которые не соответствую этому правилу:**

Однородные члены

Конкурс... проводится с 1964 года, **следовательно,** имеет богатые традиции. [И. К. Архипова. Музыка жизни (1996)] [омонимия снята] ←

Сложное предложение:

...измеренная функция масс оптической звезды превышает  абсолютный верхний предел для массы нейтронной звезды, **следовательно,** можно сразу отнести эти объекты к кандидатам в чёрные дыры. [А. М. Черепащук. Поиски чёрных дыр // «Вестник РАН», 2004]

Конструкция та же, **следовательно**, те же и проблемы. «Автопилот», 2002.08.15]

Answer (score 1):

1) **Из толкового словаря Кузнецова**

СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО. I. **вводн. сл.** Разг. Таким образом, стало быть. Так вы, с., уезжаете? Здесь, с., ошибка. **II. союз.** **(присоединяет чл. предл. и предл. со зн. следствия).** Поэтому, вследствие этого, значит.

*Отец много работает, **следовательно** очень устаёт. Свет горит, **следовательно** родители ещё не спят. Работа не окончена — **следовательно** выводы делать рано.*

2) **Толковый словарь указывает нам, где ставить запятые, хотя для этого  у нас есть официальные справочники по правописанию.**

Толковый словарь объясняет нам, что ***следовательно*** —  это **присоединительный союз со значением следствия**.  Но в "Морфологии современного русского" языка написано, что присоединительными являются союзы ***да и, также, а также, тоже***, нет среди них союза ***следовательно***.

А в "Синтаксисе современного русского языка" нет такого класса, **как присоединительные предложения**. Есть присоединительные отношения между  членами предложения, а также между простыми предложениями  в составе сложного предложения. Но это могут быть сложные предложения разного вида, в каждом случае действуют свои правила.

Короче говоря, эти "откровения" толкового словаря не выдерживают никакой критики, **они весьма далеки от академической или даже вузовской грамматики.** Но почему мы должные его слушать?

3) **Наше правописание основано на грамматике**, но у нас **нет официального  грамматического справочника**, пригодного для практического использования и соответствующего существующим правилам письма. Другими словами, у нас нет порядка, нет соответствия между разными ведомствами —  у каждого своя правильная линия.

4)  **Но при этом мы ждем всеобщей грамотности нашего населения** и удивляемся, что она никак не наступает. Тем редким пользователям, которые хотят в чем-то разобраться, сложно приходится, но, к счастью  для наших лингвистов-специалистов, **таких людей ма**ло.

Большинство российских граждан толковых словарей не читают и  слово ***следовательно*** обособляют чисто по интуиции  —  никто не собирается считать это вводное слово союзом.

5) **Нужно ли с этим бороться, можно ли это изменить?** И бороться не нужно, и изменить нельзя, потому что  спорить с системой бесполезно. Говорят, что систему может победить только другая система, таков уж закон природы.